# Can I use a 45 degree angle when dropping conduit into the ground?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, conduit

I am running electricity and internet over to a shed in my backyard.

When my conduit drops from my wall, it seems like it would be a much easier pull if it transitioned at a 45 degree angle into the trench than at a 90.

Would I be violating any normal rules regarding electrical conduit by using a 45 instead of a 90 when transitioning from wall to trench?

Comment: Unless your trench will continue down hill at a 45° to the shed, you'll need another 45° angle to make the transition to horizontal to make the run. Also, are you using electrical conduit (where pre-made bends are already long-radius sweeps designed to make pulling wire easier), or are you violating code by using plumbing pipe & bends which have much tighter radius turns?

Comment: No, using premade bends. The pipe will bend a little bit to flatten out into the trench, but I could use another 45 I guess

Comment: Plumbing Sch 40 comes with pre-made bends. They're just tighter radius than Sch 40 conduit pre-made bends. Your comment didn't really answer my question. ;)

Comment: I had some hack electrician who claimed they didn't make long radius bends and the utility failed him for using a short radius - this was for underground conduit for a 250mcw 200amp teck cable.

Comment: Remember you'll either need to use fiber-optic or a second conduit for the data.  Copper data cable cannot go in power conduit.   Also the conduit must be built, inspected, backfilled and tamped before any wires are pulled in.

Answer (score 3):

You probably *can* but it's highly impractical.

The conduit needs to be a certain depth (depending on what it's made of) underground.  It needs to hug the wall before it transitions to its horizontal run at the right depth through a 90 degree sweep.

If you enter the ground at 45 degrees:

1. the section of conduit below the ground from where it enters until the point it is at the correct depth, would have to be encased in concrete or protected in some other way from being damaged by shovels.
2. the section of conduit *above* the ground from where it comes out of the ground to the wall will also have to be protected somehow from being damaged and people tripping over it.
3. How will you access the conduit for pulling?   Is there a 45 degree pull box you can use at the top end?  I don't think so.  Or will you put another 45 degree bend on it and pull from inside the house?  That eliminates the advantage you're trying to create.

Comment: You have a point with your first point that maybe I'd need to encase the first little bit in concrete, but I don't see why 2 and 3 would be an issue.

Comment: #2 is and issue, @blake, because the conduit won't be close to the wall after the 45° bend. If it's sticking out _someone_ will trip over it, hit it with the lawnmower/weed whacker, whatever.

Comment: #3 is an issue for the same reason code prohibits more than 360° total bend between pull-boxes. There's as much friction and resistance from two 45° as there is from one 90°. Just like there's as much resistance from four 90° as one 360°.

Comment: The 45 would be way underground, not above ground, no one would trip over it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that 2 45s make a 90, but there would be less resistance for the same reason that a sweeping 90 has less resistance than a shorter 90

Comment: Weather replacing a sweeping 90 with two sweeping 45s would result in less resistance is not something I can speak to, but my guess is that the time and effort is better spent following code and traditional wisdom to produce a pullable run, and not go to great lengths to make it even more pullable.  IE, you're solving a problem that has been solved, and introducing unknowns.

Comment: Regarding #2 and 3, maybe you can add a simple sketch to your question showing ground level, your wall, and the length of pipe from inside the house to the point that it is horizontal underground.

Comment: What I mean by traditional wisdom is a straight run between buildings with a sweeping 90 at each end of the trench and a pull box directly above them. If you can't pull *that* bring in someone with experience to figure out what you're doing wrong, and save the creativity for something where you'll get real benefit out of it.